# mysql Data loss after server restart

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, data-loss

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql data loss after server crash](https://serverfault.com/questions/154065/mysql-data-loss-after-server-crash)

After the server restarted due to a power cut, we lost all data saved in the database during the morning (client records created in the website). A few minutes before the crash, I was able to see such data on "MySQL Query Browser" during some routine checks. After the crash, all records created in the morning disappeared and the most recent ones that I could see were created at 7 p.m. the day before. It seems like all INSERT statements were performed in a cache that could not be flushed because of the power cut. Does MySQL use such caching mechanism ? If yes, is it crash proof and how can I configure it ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried repairing the affected tables?

I've never lost data on that scale in MySQL: it seems to write to disk immediately. Maybe MySQL isn't the culprit here - maybe CHKDSK did that to you, or maybe you have some auto-filesystem rollback in place?

Comment: I don't know, I use ubuntu with hardware raid.